# Performance concerns on using regex in keys for dictionary

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary

I have extended this class http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/CSharpMessenger_Extended to accept strings containing wildcards as eventTypes, therefore I am able to write things like

```
Messenger.AddListener("*", () => Console.WriteLine("woohoo, generic handler"));
```

But I am highly concerned about the performance of this implementation.

I've extended the Dictionary class like this:

```
public class EventDictionary : Dictionary<string, Delegate>
    {
        public Delegate[] GetHandlers(string Event)
        {
            List<Delegate> matches = new List<Delegate>();
            foreach (string pattern in Keys)
                if (Regex.IsMatch(Event, Regex.Escape(pattern).Replace( @"\*", ".*" ).Replace( @"\?", "." )))
                    matches.Add(this[pattern]);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log(matches.Count);
            return matches.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

As you see, for every key in the dictionary, I first convert it to a regular expression, then check if it is a match for the event name, if it's so, add it to a collection and return the array.

But, this code runs in a game where the messenger script is used frequently, therefore I am really concerned about the performance of this approach.

Is my solution a acceptable way? If not what would be a better approach for solving my problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: I'd expect there would be more efficient ways to implement and achieve the same behavior. I guess the question is to what end do you need - what I interpret as - wildcard handlers?

Comment: What about storing the regexes in the dictionary? (Should not that dictionary be a multimap or just a list of tuples/pairs? What if someone adds another `*`?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing the performance of working code, which would be better suited to [codereview.se].

Comment: @GáborBakos, it is a good idea to convert wildcard expressions to regex's at adding listeners. It simply calls that handler too for every event.

Comment: Looks like you have `List<Tuple<Regex, List<Action>>`... Not sure why you use Dictionary for that and why to convert to regex every time... But other than that your code is as slow as any other implementation which needs to do linear search over all elements...

Comment: Instead of asking if there could be a problem, it might be more prudent to run the tests yourself to find out - and if there isn't an issue, don't spend any more time on it.

Comment: @TimS. you are right, I forgot about that site. I moved this to Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71573/performance-concerns-on-using-regex-in-keys-for-dictionary

Comment: @theMayer, There will not be any errors or anything like that in the code, I am not concerned about bugs, I am concerned about the performance

Comment: @FatihBAKIR, understood, and my point still stands - create and run performance tests.